# Как перевести виджет выбора цвета на русский?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, интернационализация, qcolordialog

Никак не могу сделать так, чтобы виджет выбора цвета был на русском.

На скриншоте показано то, что я хочу перевести.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже приведенный код является чисто примером взятом из интернета, по причине того, что хочу полностью разобраться с этим и уже работать со своим кодом.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class QColorButton(QPushButton):
    ''' Пользовательский виджет Qt, чтобы отобразить выбранный цвет.
    Щелчок левой кнопкой мыши на кнопке показывает выбор цвета, в то время как     
    щелчок правой кнопкой мыши сбрасывает цвет до None (без цвета).         '''

    colorChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QColorButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._color = None
        self.setWindowTitle("QColorButton(QPushButton)")
        self.setText("""
      QColorButton:

    - сделайте Left-click
        или
    - сдулайте Right-click. """)
        self.pressed.connect(self.onColorPicker)

    def setColor(self, color):
        if color != self._color:
            self._color = color
            self.colorChanged.emit()

        if self._color:
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % self._color)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet("")

    def color(self):
        return self._color

    def onColorPicker(self):
        '''  Диалоговое окно выбора цвета .
        По умолчанию Qt будет использовать собственный диалог.  '''

        dlg = QColorDialog(self)
        if self._color:
            dlg.setCurrentColor(QColor(self._color))

        if dlg.exec_():
            self.setColor(dlg.currentColor().name())

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.setColor(None)

        return super(QColorButton, self).mousePressEvent(e)

app    = QApplication([])
window = QColorButton()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Вы не принимаете ответы, почему?

Comment: @Александр извиняюсь, я забыл отметить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Путь замените на свой.

```
app = QApplication([])
PATH_LANGUAGE = r'C:\Python37\Lib\site-
packages\PyQt5\Qt5\translations\qtbase_ru.qm'
translator = QTranslator(app)
translator.load(PATH_LANGUAGE, "ru_RU")
app.installTranslator(translator)
window = QColorButton()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Думаю, лучше написать, что из папки библиотеки PyQt5 можно скопировать файлы перевода и подгружать их уже из папки программы :)

Comment: Да вы правы так будет лучше:-)

Answer (score 4):

Надо использовать механизм [интернализации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html).

```
translator = QTranslator()
locale = QLocale.system().name()   # или locale = "ru_RU" если хотите жёстко русский, а не соответствие языку системы
if translator.load(f"qtbase_{locale}", QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)):
    app.installTranslator(translator)
```